# Redirect to different page onclick of button in Secha Ext JS

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have created a login page, on click of button, I want to load a new page. how can I achieve that?

***I have tried:***

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'login'
   });
```

Comment: do you want to redirect to new url or create new view in that page?

Comment: I want to create a new view.

Comment: You should check some tutorials in [ExtJS docs.](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/login_app.html)

Answer (score 0):

If 'login' is of type Window or Panel (so a kind of container), you can call show() method after creation.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to remove login page view, after create new view and render it. for example.

1. get access to top level element. in most case it's viewport and remove all child elements.

   `var topLvlElement = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("viewport")[0]
        topLvlElement .removeAll()`
2. create new view and add it in top level element

   `var newView = Ext.create("myapp.view.mainPage",{title:"mainPage"});
   topLvlElement .add(newView);`